# Ring buffer log file on unix

Tags: unix, logging, pipeline, tail

I'm trying to come up with a unix pipeline of commands that will allow me to log only the most recent *n* lines of a program's output to a text file.

The text file should never be more than *n* lines long.  (it may be less when it is first filling the file)

It will be run on a device with limited memory/resources, so keeping the filesize small is a priority.

I've tried stuff like this (n=500):

```
program_spitting_out_text > output.txt
cat output.txt | tail -500 > recent_output.txt
rm output.txt
```

or

```
program_spitting_out_text | tee output.txt | tail -500 > recent_output.txt
```

Obviously neither works for my purposes...

Anyone have a good way to do this in a one-liner? Or will I have to write a script/utility?

Note: I don't want anything to do with dmesg and must use standard BSD unix commands.  The "program_spitting_out_text" prints out about 60 lines/second, every second.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `program_spitting_out_text` hold the file open or does it open/close per log line output?

Comment: More importantly - assuming you want the log why would you want only a few transient lines.  Suppose you get an error condition.  Do you plan on reading the thing realtime?  That is what this design would take.  You need to consider moving the data off somewhere else.  Otherwise do not bother with the log at all.

Comment: what's the problem with your second option? (leaving out the `tee` part of course)

Comment: @paxdiablo Good question that I don't know the answer to.  Since the *program_spitting_out_text* is just printing text to the screen, is it really up to the program how the " > output.txt" behaves?  I would assume that this line *program_spitting_out_text > output.txt* would hold the file open.

Comment: @jimmcnamara  *program_spitting_out_text* will die at a certain point.  I'd like to capture the 500 lines of output before it does so.

Comment: @Diego The problem is that *output.txt* will still grow to be a huge file over time.

Comment: That's why I suggested to leave tee out (it's the only command writing the full output in that pipeline). The only problem I see is that `recent_output.txt` will only be updated at the end; but if you are ok with that go for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `program_spitting_out_text` runs continuously and keeps it's file open, there's not a lot you can do.

Even deleting the file won't help since it will still continue to write to the now "hidden" file (data still exists but there is no directory entry for it) until it closes it, at which point it will be really removed.

---

If it closes and reopens the log file periodically (every line or every ten seconds or whatever), then you have a relatively easy option.

Simply monitor the file until it reaches a certain size, then roll the file over, something like:

```
while true; do
    sleep 5
    lines=$(wc -l <file.log)
    if [[ $lines -ge 5000 ]]; then
        rm -f file2.log
        mv file.log file2.log
        touch file.log
    fi
done
```

This script will check the file every five seconds and, if it's 5000 lines or more, will move it to a backup file. The program writing to it will continue to write to that backup file (since it has the open handle to it) until it closes it, then it will re-open the new file.

This means you will always have (roughly) between five and ten thousand lines in the log file set, and you can search them with commands that combine the two:

```
grep ERROR file2.log file.log
```

---

Another possibility is if you can restart the program periodically without affecting its function. By way of example, a program which looks for the existence of a file once a second and reports on that, can probably be restarted without a problem. One calculating PI to a hundred billion significant digits will probably *not* be restartable without impact.

If it *is* restartable, then you can basically do the same trick as above. When the log file reaches a certain size, kill of the current program (which you will have started as a background task from your script), do whatever magic you need to in rolling over the log files, then restart the program.

For example, consider the following (restartable) program `prog.sh` which just continuously outputs the current date and time:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while true; do
    date
done
```

Then, the following script will be responsible for starting and stopping the other script as needed, by checking the log file every five seconds to see if it has exceeded its limits:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

exe=./prog.sh
log1=prog.log
maxsz=500

pid=-1
touch ${log1}
log2=${log1}-prev

while true; do
    if [[ ${pid} -eq -1 ]]; then
        lines=${maxsz}
    else
        lines=$(wc -l <${log1})
    fi
    if [[ ${lines} -ge ${maxsz} ]]; then
        if [[ $pid -ge 0 ]]; then
            kill $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi
        sleep 1
        rm -f ${log2}
        mv ${log1} ${log2}
        touch ${log1}
        ${exe} >> ${log1} &
        pid=$!
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

And this output (from an every-second `wc -l` on the two log files) shows what happens at the time of switchover, noting that it's approximate only, due to the delays involved in switching:

```
474 prog.log       0 prog.log-prev
496 prog.log       0 prog.log-prev
518 prog.log       0 prog.log-prev
539 prog.log       0 prog.log-prev
542 prog.log       0 prog.log-prev
 21 prog.log     542 prog.log-prev
```

Now keep in mind that's a sample script. It's *relatively* intelligent but probably needs some error handling so that it doesn't leave the executable running if you shut down the monitor.

---

And, finally, if none of that suffices, there's nothing stopping you from writing your *own* filter program which takes standard input and continuously outputs that to a real ring buffer file.

Then you would simply do:

```
program_spitting_out_text | ringbuffer 4096 last4k.log
```

That program could be a true ring buffer in that it treats the 4k file as a circular character buffer but, of course, you'll need a special marker in the file to indicate the write-point, along with a program that can turn it back into a real stream.

Or, it could do much the same as the scripts above, rewriting the file so that it's always below the size desired.

Comment: Thanks, @paxdiablo. I thought about this ping-ponging between logfiles approach, but I was hoping I was overlooking some cool one-liner that would get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Since apparently this basic feature (circular file) does not exist on GNU/Linux, and because I needed it to track logs on my Raspberry Pi with limited storage, I just wrote the code as suggest above!

Behold: [circFS](https://gitlab.com/BylonAkila/circfs/-/tree/master)

Unlike other tools quoted on this post and other similar, the maximum size is arbitrary and only limited by the actual available storage.
It does not rotate with several files, all is kept in the single file, which is rewritten on "release".
You can have as many log files as needed in the virtual directory.

It is a single C file (~600 lines including comments), and it builds with a single compile line after having installed fuse development dependencies.

This first version is very basic (see the README), if you want to improve it with some of the TODOs (see the TODO) be welcome to submit pull requests.

As a joke, this is my first **"write only"** fuse driver! :-)